# How to set default value for a textfield inside for In Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have a for loop where I am showing the selected product name and price. The user has an option to enter the quantity but by default, the quantity should be 1. How I can set the text field value with a default value of 1.

I have tried the following way but it's not working:

```
<tr *ngFor="let spro of selectedProd;let i = index;">
    <td data-title="Product Name">{{spro.product_description}}</td>
    <td data-title="Unit Price" class="numeric">
        <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>2000</td>
    <td data-title="Qty" class="numeric">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedProd[i].qty" name="qty" value="1">
    </td>
    <td data-title="Total Price" class="numeric">
        <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>{{selectedProd[i].qty*2000}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: OP you problem is that ngModel is overriding anything you have in the value field and that's for good and you won't be able to change this. In your component class you need to go through all values and set the defaults there. This is the only correct solution

Answer (score 4):

use `value` placed in square brackets:

```
[value]="myDefaultValue"
```

in component:

```
myDefaultValue: number = 1;
```

or use one way binding:

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="selectedProd[i].qty" name="qty" value="1">
```

Comment: can you use one way binding? if yes, try this:  
`<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="selectedProd[i].qty" name="qty" value="1">`

Comment: No it is not. It is evaluating number 1 to 1

Comment: but this not multiplying with the amount

Answer (score 3):

Two possible solutions:

1. Try to set a default value to the bound data first.
2. Use placeholder tag.

   [working demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KaLNhLfNVrlpOH9358yh)

   ```
   import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
   import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
   import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 

   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `
       <div>

         <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myValue" name="qty1">
         <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myValue2" name="qty2" placeholder="1">

       </div>
     `,
   })
   export class App {
     myValue:string;
     myValue2:string;

     constructor() {
       this.myValue = "default value";
     }
   }

   @NgModule({
     imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
     declarations: [ App ],
     bootstrap: [ App ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```

Here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KaLNhLfNVrlpOH9358yh) with ngFor and bound attribute placeholders:

```
     <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.value" name="qty1"  [attr.placeholder]="price * qua" >
     </ng-container>
...
  items = [{value:null}, {value:"defVal"}];

  public qua = 3;
  public price = 7;
```

Comment: this is inside for loop.How can I set default value in component?

Comment: you have added the default value in placeholder. I want to multiply quantity with price. Then this placeholder wont work

Comment: did it help you?

Comment: you are adding the default value as a placeholder.I want it as an actual value

Comment: then your only solution is to initialize the object you (two-way) bind. `item.value = "your def. value here" `

Answer (score 0):

These are your options

```
[value]="myObject"
[value]="'This is a string'"
value="This is a string"
```

Comment: I tried this but not working. Can you send me a full line of code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> product.component.html

```html
<tr *ngFor="let spro of selectedProd;let i = index;">
    <td data-title="Product Name">{{spro.product_description}}</td>
    <td data-title="Unit Price" class="numeric">
        <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>2000</td>
    <td data-title="Qty" class="numeric">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedQuantity" (ngModelChange)="quantityChanged($event, i)" name="qty">
    </td>
    <td data-title="Total Price" class="numeric">
        <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>{{selectedProd[i].qty*2000}}</td>
</tr>
```

> product.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: 'product.component.html'
})
export class ProductComponent {
  public selectedProduct: any;
  public selectedQuantity: number = 1;

  constructor() {  }

  quantityChanged(e: any, index : any) {
     //event comes as parameter, you'll have to find selected data manually using event.target element
     this.selectedQuantity = e.target.qty;
     this.selectedProd[i].qty = this.selectedQuantity;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

import **FormsModule** in the appModule.
use **([ngModel])** in the html input element. `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="defaultQuantity"/>` and in the component create a variable name **defaultQuantity:number=1;**