# Angular Reactive Forms- Setting Default Values of *ngFor List of Replies to Posts

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to set a score for a specific reply out of a list of replies.  Originally, I tried to set the default value using the input value attribute.  When I just submit the default values, I receive empty strings.  When I change the values of the input fields, these values are passed back to a function successfully.

These sources- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644131/how-to-set-default-value-for-a-textfield-inside-for-in-angular-4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976845/reactive-form-not-receive-default-input-value) - have helped me understand why this won't work.  The empty string or default values I set in my .ts file override the value in the .html file.  I also tried to use ngModel, but had similar problems.

I'm still struggling to understand how to set the default values when I have many replies that can be individually scored.  Could anyone help me understand how to set the default values in this situation?

HTML File

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let reply of replies">
    <mat-card-title>
        {{reply.title}}
        {{reply.user}}
    </mat-card-title>

    <mat-card-content>
        {{reply.content}}
    </mat-card-content>

    <mat-card-actions>
        <form [formGroup]="feedbackForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input matInput formControlName="id" placeholder="id" type="hidden" value="{{reply._id}}>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input matInput formControlName="grade" placeholder="Enter Grade" type="number" value="{{reply.grade}}>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" (click)="feedbackResponse">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

TypeScript File

```
public ngOnInit() {

    this.replies = [{
        "_id": "dkjldajl",
        "user": "Person 1",
        "title": "Person 1's Reply",
        "content": "The content that Person 1 wrote.",
        "grade": 0   
    }, {
        "_id": "danlkanl",
        "user": "Person 2",
        "title": "Person 2's Reply",
        "content": "The content that Person 2 wrote.",
        "grade": 0   
    }]

    this.feedbackForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      id: ['', Validators.required],
      grade: ['']
    })

    //How can I set the values?
       this.feedbackForm.get('id').setValue(???)
       this.feedbackForm.get('grade').setValue(???)
    //
}
  get id() {
    return this.feedbackForm.get('id');
  }

  get grade() {
    return this.feedbackForm.get('grade');
  }

feedbackResponse() {
    console.log(this.replyFeedbackForm)
}
```

Comment: you need to create array of formgroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactive form source of truth is based on class not template so you can't bind any data from template

Since you are getting array of data you need to create array of formGroup like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  feedbackForm: FormGroup;
  replies = [{
    "_id": "dkjldajl",
    "user": "Person 1",
    "title": "Person 1's Reply",
    "content": "The content that Person 1 wrote.",
    "grade": 0
  }, {
    "_id": "danlkanl",
    "user": "Person 2",
    "title": "Person 2's Reply",
    "content": "The content that Person 2 wrote.",
    "grade": 0
  }]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    const controls = this.replies.map((c => this.fb.group({
      id: c._id,
      user: c.user,
      grade: c.grade,
      content: c.content
    })))

    this.feedbackForm = this.fb.group({
      replies: this.fb.array(controls)
    })
  }
  get repliesControl() {
    return this.feedbackForm.get('replies');
  }
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjunx6